# Installing gdb on Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gdb

I'm trying to install gdb on mac and seems to be hitting one issue after another. Well for starters I've X-Code command line tools installed on the system. When I initially ran gdb, I'd get

```
gdb: command not found
```

k so I go ahead and install it

```
brew install gdb
```

It does the installation and comes up with the following issue

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/info/annotate.info
/usr/local/share/info is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link gdb
```

So I try again,

```
brew link gdb

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.8... 
Error: Could not symlink share/info/annotate.info
/usr/local/share/info is not writable.

I try giving write permission to the folder

cd /usr/local/share/info
```

Thus I do what it wants me to do,

```
| => chmod +r annotate.info
chmod: annotate.info: No such file or directory
```

The saga continues, now where I stand is

```
| => brew install gdb
Warning: gdb-7.8 already installed, it's just not linked
```

How can I link gdb and get it working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `chmod +w /usr/local/share/info`. `+r` only adds read permission.

Comment: OS X has moved over to using lldb as the debugger. The version of gdb available through brew probably does not include Apple's patches that were used for gdb when gdb was the OS X system debugger, and so it may not work well in that environment. If you don't have a specific need for gdb then using lldb is probably a better option for you. (It is installed with the command line tools.)

Comment: @bames53 The latest GDB in Homebrew actually does work pretty well, in my experience anyway. The version prior, not so much.